# StandardSQL: I want to extract only inside brackets

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I tried to extract detail of user agent.

e.g.) `Android App 1.1.1 (SO-02J, OS 5.0.4)`
Ideal result: `SO-02J, OS 5.0.4`

I tried this.
`REGEXP_EXTRACT(Android App 1.1.1 (SO-02J, OS 5.0.4),'(?<=\().*?(?=\))')`
But BigQuery use re2 not support after/before text matching.

https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

How do I get inside of brackets..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get inside of brackets?

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT('Android App 1.1.1 (SO-02J, OS 5.0.4)', r'\((.*?)\)')
```

Above extracts content inside first pars of brackets - in this case `SO-02J, OS 5.0.4`